# Javascript moment subtract lunchtime from workhours

Tags: javascript, subtraction

I want to subtract lunch hours from datetime differece
How it can be achieved?

```
var StartTime = moment(theList[i].start_time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); //2020-04-01 08:00:00.0
    var EndTime = moment(theList[i].end_time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); //2020-04-01 18:00:00.0
    var Lunch = moment(theList[i].lunch_time, "HH:mm:ss"); //00:30:00
    var lunchTimeMs= moment(Lunch,"HH:mm:ss");

    var ms = moment(EndTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(StartTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    var d = moment.duration(ms);
    ms = moment().subtract(lunchTimeMs); //This gives wrong result


    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

    console.log("Total time " + i + " row" + s);
```

Comment: Please try to avoid asking a question without giving sufficient information about your issue that would be required for anyone to solve it. Edit your question and add a tag to indicate which programming language this is. Also, what is this method `moment`?

Comment: edited hope now everyone understands

Comment: what is  datetime , and how it is to be calculated?

Comment: what do you mean by datetime?

Answer (score 2):

He is using [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/).

As far as I understood, the problem is that he has only date with time to manipulate in format similar to: `dd.mm.YYYY HH:ii:ss`.

My recommendation was to transfer server response datetime to timestamp using [JS](https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/convert-date-timestamp-javascript). It's much easier to manipulate date and time differences if you are using a timestamp.

**UPDATE**

Adding here my "vision" of JS date management (my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unoteu/xgpwy90d/12/)). Feel free to improve it!

```js
const date2timestamp= function(str){
 _tmp = str.split(" ");
 if(_tmp){
  date_arr = ( _tmp[1] ? _tmp[0].split("-") : null );
  time_arr = ( _tmp[1] ? _tmp[1].split(":") : _tmp[0].split(":") );
  if(!date_arr) {
   const today = new Date(); 
   _date = Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), time_arr[0], time_arr[1], time_arr[2]);
     }
  else {
   _date = Date.UTC(date_arr[0], date_arr[1]-1, date_arr[2], time_arr[0], time_arr[1], time_arr[2]);
  }
  date_obj = new Date(_date);
  return date_obj.getTime()/1000;
 }
 return false;
}

document.write(
 date2timestamp("2020-04-20 08:00:00")+"<br/>",
 date2timestamp("2020-04-20 17:00:00")+"<br/>",
 date2timestamp("00:03:00")
);
```

And now you have timestamps. When you subtract, you know, that the 1min = 60sec, so the result is `((7*60)+30)*60 = date2timestamp("2020-04-20 17:00:00")-date2timestamp("2020-04-20 17:00:00")-(30*60)`

**MORE UPDATES**

But, reading about the moment.js a bit, there is even easier way. [Manual](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) for subtract says:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'seconds');
```

that means, you have to actually transfer your Launch period into seconds and then add put it into the subtract: `moment().subtract((30*60), 'seconds')` or just add (for test) 'millisecond' as second part of subtract:

```
...
ms = moment().subtract(lunchTimeMs, 'milliseconds');
// or use that
ms = moment().subtract(lunchTimeMs/1000, 'seconds);
...
```

Comment: how it can be achieved?

Comment: What format the value **theList[i].start_time** has? Can you dump us the theList[i] values? I recommend some actual data to print out. Not sure, what language you use, but for JS: `for(var i in theList) console.log(theList[i]);` and then check console.

Comment: Edited now it should be visible

Comment: I added my "vision".

Comment: Sorry but this isnt working.:( It looks like almost correct solution. It substracts time but get result  -1:43:47 with lunch time 00:30:00 start time 2020-04-01 08:00:00.0 and with end time 2020-04-01 18:00:00.0

Comment: Yeah .. you only get timestamps here .. but there is a way. all you need to do, is some extra calculations .. but, as I understood, you did it in server side, so .. even better! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var StartTime = moment(theList[i].start_time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var EndTime = moment(theList[i].end_time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var Lunch = moment(theList[i].lunch_time, "HH:mm:ss");
    var ms = moment(EndTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(StartTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    moment(ms).subtract(Lunch);
```

Comment: ms.subtract is not a function

Comment: note that real date is with millisecond .0 at the end. Does it play role?